# Como interpolar valores de profundidade de solo usando "spline"? Ou usando o pacote "aqp"?

Tags: r

Olá, eu gostaria de interpolar os valores de profundidade de solo nas colunas `"top"` e `"bottom"`, (a cada 5 unidades) nos dados de solo, como por exemplo, no dataframe:

```
id_num    id_name horiz  top bottom  K   Mg   Ca CEC_7 ex_Ca_to_Mg sand silt clay   CF
1          colusa    A   0      12 0.3 25.7  9.0  23.0        0.35   46   33   21 0.12
2          colusa  ABt   12     28 0.2 23.7  5.6  21.4        0.23   42   31   27 0.27
3          colusa  Bt1   28     52 0.1 23.2  1.9  23.7        0.08   40   28   32 0.27
5           glenn    A   0       9 0.2 21.9  4.4  18.8        0.20   54   20   25 0.55
6           glenn   Bt   9      34 0.3 18.9  4.5  27.5        0.20   49   18   34 0.84
```

Então tenho `(top-bottom = 0-12, 12-28, 28-52, ...)` e **eu gostaria de obter** as colunas `"top"` e `"bottom"` interpoladas por 5 unidades (cm neste caso) como por exemplo `(top-bottom = 0-5, 5-10, 10-15, 15-20, 20-25, 25-30, 30-35, 35-40, 40-45, 45-50, ...)`, interpolando valores e repetindo as outras colunas correspondentes como `id_num`, `id_name` e `horiz`, como por exemplo:

```
id_num    id_name horiz  top bottom  K   Mg   Ca CEC_7 ex_Ca_to_Mg sand silt clay   CF
1          colusa    A   0       5 0.3 25.7  9.0  23.0        0.35   46   33   21 0.12
1          colusa    A   5      10 0.3 25.7  9.0  23.0        0.35   46   33   21 0.12
2          colusa  ABt   10     15 0.2 23.7  5.6  21.4        0.23   42   31   27 0.27
2          colusa  ABt   15     20 0.2 23.7  5.6  21.4        0.23   42   31   27 0.27
2          colusa  ABt   20     25 0.2 23.7  5.6  21.4        0.23   42   31   27 0.27
3          colusa  Bt1   25     30 0.1 23.2  1.9  23.7        0.08   40   28   32 0.27
3          colusa  Bt1   30     35 0.1 23.2  1.9  23.7        0.08   40   28   32 0.27
3          colusa  Bt1   35     40 0.1 23.2  1.9  23.7        0.08   40   28   32 0.27
3          colusa  Bt1   40     45 0.1 23.2  1.9  23.7        0.08   40   28   32 0.27
3          colusa  Bt1   45     50 0.1 23.2  1.9  23.7        0.08   40   28   32 0.27
5           glenn    A   0       5 0.2 21.9  4.4  18.8        0.20   54   20   25 0.55
5           glenn    A   5      10 0.2 21.9  4.4  18.8        0.20   54   20   25 0.55
6           glenn   Bt   10     15 0.3 18.9  4.5  27.5        0.20   49   18   34 0.84
6           glenn   Bt   15     20 0.3 18.9  4.5  27.5        0.20   49   18   34 0.84
6           glenn   Bt   20     25 0.3 18.9  4.5  27.5        0.20   49   18   34 0.84
6           glenn   Bt   25     30 0.3 18.9  4.5  27.5        0.20   49   18   34 0.84
6           glenn   Bt   30     35 0.3 18.9  4.5  27.5        0.20   49   18   34 0.84
```

Obs: Neste exemplo os valores não estão interpolados (apenas repetidos).

O conjunto de dados de exemplo pode ser visto com o comando `data(sp4)`.

Tentei a função `slice` do pacote `aqp` com:

```
data(sp4) #obter o conjunto de dados de solo de exemplo
depths(sp4) <- id ~ top + bottom #ajustar os dados para o pacote `aqp` package
sliced <- slice(sp4, fm= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50) ~ sand + silt + clay + name + ex_Ca_to_Mg, just.the.data=TRUE)
```

Mas obtive:

```
(top-bottom = 0-1, 5-6, 10-11, 15-16, 20-21, 25-26, 30-31, 35-36, 40-41, 45-46, ...)
```

ao invés de:

```
(top-bottom = 0-5, 5-10, 10-15, 15-20, 20-25, 25-30, 30-35, 35-40, 40-45, 45-50, ...)
```

Também tentei a função `slab`, mas não funcionou comigo, ainda.

Sugestões com **`spline`** são muito bem vindas!

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Primeiro você terá que reorganizar a sua tabela, de modo que cada coluna represente um perfil de solo.

2) O intervalo dos valores a serem preditos devem apresentar 'NA'. Ex:

```
0.3
NA
NA
0.2
```

3) Instale a `library(zoo)`;

4) Organize todos os seus dados em um `data.frame();`
utilize a função `na.spline():`

```
data.frame('id' = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 6, NA, NA, NA, 6.5)) -> exemplo
na.spline(exemplo) -> exemplo_preenchido
print(exemplo_preenchido)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Michel!!! Ótima solução! Simples e rápida.
Vou organizar os dados e postarei os comandos! (pode demorar um pouco...)